# Twitter reverse auth credentials suddenly stopped working on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I have been using reverse auth in my Twitter app for a year now. This morning my app reverse auth stopped working. After doing some inspecting, I found out that I am receiving an error message that states "Reverse auth credentials are invalid." This is extremely confusing to me, as I have changed nothing. I have emailed Twitter but haven't heard back yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just noticed a similar issue in our app. Unfortunately the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/archive/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) is no longer accessible.

Changing the HTTP method of the initial `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token` request from `GET` to `POST` fixed it for us.